# What's a word for watching something in horror?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing an essay about Mark Twain. In his early life, specifically at age 10, he "had to watch" or saw first a local man murder a cattle rancher, and second "watched" a slave die after a white overseer struck him with a piece of iron. What is a more correct word to replace the phrases in quotations?

I tried using Thesaurus.com to find a synonym but none quite fit the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can be **transfixed** by horror.

One can **witness** such events.